# Python 2.7 / Windows 7 / Tkinter: Center transient child window over parent

Tags: python, tkinter, windows-7

As I understood from the Tkinter reference, a transient child window is drawn (centered?) on its parent window. This works for me in Linux but not in Windows (7).

Do you have any suggestions why this happens?

I can center the window manually with the .geometry() method, but when the GUI is calculating some values (say for a second) then there is a small window appearing with no GUI at all which then flits to the specified position even when I call the .withdraw method.

Thanks a lot!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

class Parent(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.txt = tk.Text(master=self)
        self.txt.pack()
        self.btn = ttk.Button(master=self, text='Show Child',
                              command=self.show)
        self.btn.pack()
        self.mainloop()

    def show(self, *args):
        Child(self)


class Child(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.txt = tk.Text(master=self)
        self.txt.pack()

Parent()
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved this the following way:

- `.withdraw()` the window
- set the `.geometry()` to center over parent window
- do some calculation to get the desired UI
- `.update_idletasks()`
- finally `.deiconify()` the window.